# Time Series: existence of moments $\Rightarrow$ existence of distribution?

Tags: measure-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

This might come to you as a bit silly, because normally we are used to the vice-versa question. But here is what I have: a nonlinear time-series model, for which I can derive by infinite backwards iteration the mean and a limiting bound for variance. Now I just want to say that therefore a stationary distribution must exist.

Is this true? Any deep reason why?

[Of course moments are derived in terms of the distribution in the first place, but is this the argument?]

Comment: Where is the stationarity supposed to come from?

Comment: clarification: if f_t+1 has the same representation as f_t. This representation uses infinite history. Therefore, when this representation exists in the sense of having a well-behaved distribution, it is time-invariant and the sequence is therefore stationary. Under constraints on the recurrence relation I can calculate moments of this representation, which involves an infinite history of shocks. (might still be a bit unclear, in which case I will clarify.)

Comment: more bluntly: f_{t+1}=X and f_{t}=X, where X is some random quantity. E[X]=0 and Var[X]<const.?=>f_{t+1}=f_{t} in distribution? (allowing only for non-anticipative solutions, that is..)